# Downgrade my @angular/compiler-cli version from 8.2.13 to 6.1.10

Tags: angular

Hi All i am stuck to deploy my project in angular 6
when i check my version.

```
ng v
```

i fund below version details [image]

I want to downgrade my @angular/compiler-CLI version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm i @angular/compiler-cli@6.1.10
```

you can target a version using the last @version, using the `-g` flag to install globally

Comment: npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@6.1.10.

Comment: @ArjunWalmiki The version I typed was the one in your title. You can find all targetable versions here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli

Comment: i try with multiple version but every time same error "npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@6.1.9.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist."

Comment: Thank you i have accept your solution because you are right